# Yaml to Pojo with Jackson (objectMapper.readValue error)

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, pojo

Parsing yaml to pojo,

```
public class JacksonParse {
    public void ParseToPojo() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("input.yaml");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        Phase phase = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Phase.class);
    }
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'phase': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 1, column: 7]
```

Phase class is a model.

Comment: Have you validated your yaml before parsing ? It may be the case that yaml is incorrect

Comment: yes i did, its valid, i even tried realy simple yaml and still didnt work

Comment: Can you share your pojo , and yaml file . Also you can check the link below for the reference , though in this they are converting json to pojo unlike your case but you can get some idea . 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69790374/unrecognized-token-message-was-expecting-json-string-number-array-object